# Why does the function Image not yield a proper output?

Tags: image

Can I get the exact reason why the function `Image` doesn't yield a proper output in the below?

```
Image[TreeForm@{1, 2, 3}]
```

It shows an error message as below.

```
Image::imgarray: The specified argument  should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>
```

Is there anyway not to use the function Rasterize for get an image for the TreeForm expression?

Comment: You don't need `Image` just use `TreeForm@{1,2,3}`

Comment: `Rasterize` works, assuming you want a raster whats wrong with that?

Comment: `Graphics[Inset[TreeForm@{1, 2, 3}]]` gets you a graphic object.. (trying to guess what you want.. )

Comment: @george2079, or `ToExpression@ToBoxes@TreeForm@{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @george2079 Thanks a lot. That is what I wanted!

Comment: @Simon Woods, Thank you for your reply, as well. That is also relevant. I just want to see why this happens. I wonder about how the function Image takes the arguments and distinguishes its arguments syntactically.

Comment: @george2079 Actually I saw an post that says `Image[]` also does the same work as `Rasterize[]`, even more efficiently. So I have used `Image[]` instead of `Rasterize[]`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the `Graphics` representation of `TreeForm`, you'll need to convert it to boxes first, and then convert these boxes into a `Graphics` expression. The reason is that `TreeForm` is a special display form, and is converted directly into boxes for display without actually being evaluated into `Graphics` by the kernel.

```
g = TreeForm[{1, 2, 3}] // MakeBoxes // ToExpression;
Head[g] (* -> Graphics *)
```

You don't mention in the question what you want to do with this output, but if you use `Image` on this `Graphics`, you will indeed get a raster image. (Personally, I think this application of `Image` is misguided. `Image` is nominally supposed to *represent* a raster image based on given pixel values, not create one from other objects, which is the job of `Raster`...)

I will note that the result of `Image[g]` is identical to that of `Rasterize[TreeForm[{1, 2, 3}], "Image"]`, so it's not clear to me what you hoped to avoid by refusing to use `Rasterize` here.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
{1, 2, 3} // TreeForm
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Reference:**

[TreeForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html)